# uploading multiple files with pyramid

Tags: python, file-upload, pyramid

Trying to upload multiple files at once using python. The upload.html source code is as followed:

```
        <form name="frmRegister" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
             <div class="control-group">
                 <div class="controls">
                    <input type="file" name="files" multiple='multiple'>
                 </div>
             </div>
             <div class="control-group">
                 <div class="controls">
                    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Add Product" />
                 </div>
             </div>
        </form>
```

in my admin.py:

```
    @view_config(context="mycart:resources.Product", name="add", renderer='admin/mall/product/add.jinja2', permission = 'admin')
    @view_config(context="mycart:resources.Product", name="add", request_method="POST",  renderer='admin/mall/product/add.jinja2', permission = 'admin')
    def product_add(context, request):
        if 'btnSubmit' in request.POST:
            print ("files >>> ", request.POST['files'])
```

in my terminal, it is showing just FieldStorage('files', u'DSC01973.JPG') whereas I've selected 'DSC01975.JPG', 'DSC01976.JPG'.

Why is this so?

Comment: I don't have a Pyramid environment next to me right now (on iPad). Check `request.POST`, `request.POST.items`?

Comment: thanks for the response, i've already fixed it by using request.POST.getall

Comment: Great! I know Django has `getlist` or something similar. Good luck! Write your solution as answer, please so others can benefit. Also, if you have spare time, check my thoughts and see what you are getting. It will help me and others as well.

Comment: Sure, I'm not using django, just learning pyramid, but thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 10):

I've found a way to solve it, I believe there are many others, if there are, please feel free to holler out:

```
    fileslist = request.POST.getall('files')
    print ("My files listing: ", fileslist)
    for f in fileslist:
        print ( "individual files: ", f )
```

Answer (score 1):

I could solve the problem with the following function:

```
from cgi import FieldStorage
def get_all_file_data_list(request):
    return [x for x in request.POST.values() if isinstance(x, FieldStorage)]
```