# Uploading multiple files at once in pyramid

Tags: javascript, python, html, sqlalchemy, pyramid

Am trying to find a way of uploading multiple files using mako for example a full album of mp3 songs at once. I can only upload one at the moment. Also inquiring how i can as-well capture or store the song path in the database as I upload it to filesystem storage

```
if request.method == 'POST':   
    filename = request.params['mp3'].filename
    input_file = request.POST['mp3'].file

    file_path = os.path.join('/var/www/beatstore', '%s.mp3' % uuid.uuid4())

    temp_file_path = file_path + '~'
    output_file = open(temp_file_path, 'wb')

    # Finally write the data to a temporary file
    input_file.seek(0)
    while True:
        data = input_file.read(2<<16)
        if not data:
            break
        output_file.write(data)

    output_file.close()

    # Now that we know the file has been fully saved to disk move it into place.
    os.rename(temp_file_path, file_path)
    return {'project':'beatstore'}
```

Here is my form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="save_file.py" method="post">
    <p>File: <input type="mp3" name="mp3"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Upload"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: You'll want to look at modifying your `<input>` tag to add the multiple attribute. See: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_multiple.asp

Comment: You can then get a list of all the files with the getall() property: request.POST.getall('mp3'). More info [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051298/uploading-multiple-files-with-pyramid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051298/uploading-multiple-files-with-pyramid)